# Cant access List from another Class

Tags: c#, list, class

I am trying to access the `List` in a `Class` so I can use the values in an `Insert` statement in another. The idea is that I am filling the `List` using a `for loop` with values from an excel spreadsheet (takes place in the LegalTransactionList `Class`). I am then going to take these values and `insert` them into a database table (takes place in the Helpers `Class`). I am receiving an error on the lstOfTran.AccountNumber which states that LegalTransactionRec does not contain a definition for AccountNumber. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
class LegalTransactionList
{

    public static List<LegalTransactionRec> setTransactions()
    {
        Form1 form = new Form1();
        Workbook workbook = form.excelApp.Workbooks.Open(form.txtbxFilename.Text);

        List<LegalTransactionRec> lstTran = new List<LegalTransactionRec>();

        try
        {

            //workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(txtbxFilename.Text);                      View above comment
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range xlRange = worksheet.UsedRange;

            int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
            int colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;

            for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j <= colCount; j++)
                {
                    lstTran.Add(new LegalTransactionRec()
                    {
                        AccountNumber = Form1.CleanString(xlRange.Cells[i, 1].Value2.ToString()),
                        CostAmount = Form1.TryToParse(Form1.CleanAmount(xlRange.Cells[i, 3].Value2.ToString())),
                        SSN = Form1.CleanString(xlRange.Cells[i, 6].Value2.ToString()),
                        TransactionDate = Form1.CheckDate(xlRange.Cells[i, 2].Value2.ToDate()),
                        Description = xlRange.Cells[i, 8].Value2.ToString(),
                        TransactionCode = Form1.CheckNull(xlRange.Cells[i, 4].Value2.ToInt())
                    });
                }
            }

            if (form.validateHeader(worksheet))
            {




            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        return lstTran;

    }
}
```

---

```
class Helpers
{
    public void insertRecords()
    {
        StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
        var lstOfTran = LegalTransactionList.setTransactions();

        using (DataTable dt = DataManager.GetData(sql))
        {
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                try
                {
                    sql.AppendLine("INSERT INTO LEGAL_TRANSCATIONS (BATCH_ID, ACCOUNT, ATTORNEY_ID, ORG_ID, TRANSACTION_DATE, DATE_INSERTED, TRANSACTION_CODE, AMOUNT, DESCRIPTION, DEBTOR_SSN");
                    sql.AppendLine("VALUES ( (select max(batch_id) from legal_transaction_batch_info)," + lstOfTran.AccountNumber + );
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                { }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class LegalTransactionRec
{
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
    public string CostAmount { get; set; }
    public string SSN { get; set; }
    public int BatchID { get; set; }
    public Attorney Attorney { get; set; }
    public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int TransactionCode { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
public int CheckNull(int intVal)
    {
        int cleanValue;
        if (intVal == null)
        {
            throw new System.ArgumentException("Value cannot be null", "original");
        }
        else
        {
            cleanValue = intVal;
        }

        return cleanValue;
    }

    public string CleanString(String strVal)
    {
        string cleanValue;
        if (strVal == null)
        {
            throw new System.ArgumentException("Value cannot be null", "original");
        }
        else
        {
            cleanValue = Regex.Replace(strVal, " ", "").Replace("$", "").Replace("-", "");
        }

        return cleanValue;
    }

    public string CleanAmount(String amt)
    {
        string cleanAmt;
        if (amt == null)
        {
            throw new System.ArgumentException("Value cannot be null", "original");
        }
        else
        {
            cleanAmt = Regex.Replace(amt, "(", "-").Replace(")", "").Replace("$", "").Replace("[^0-9]+", "").Replace(" ", "");
        }
        return cleanAmt;
    }

    public static void TryToParse(string strAmt)
    {
        decimal decAmt;

        bool result = Decimal.TryParse(strAmt, out decAmt);

    }

    public DateTime CheckDate(DateTime tranDate)
    {
        DateTime date;

        if (tranDate == null)
        {
            throw new System.ArgumentException("Value cannot be null", "original");
        }
        else
        {
            date = tranDate;
        }

        return date;
    }
```

Comment: _Does_ `LegalTransactionRec` contain an `AccountNumber` property?

Comment: Also, DON'T swallow exceptions - take out the empty `catch{}` blocks and either _handle_ the error or let it bubble up.

Comment: Adding `LegalTransactionRec` Class into OP.

Comment: @DStanley This is a very rough draft, I like to get the bones of the program working before I add that sort of stuff. I know it might not be the best way to go about things but since I am learning C# this is how I like going about things. Thank you though.

Comment: Then just don't add try/catch in the first place and let any error bubble up naturally.  You'll spend a LOT more time trying to figure out _where_ errors are occurring because they get thrown out by the catch block.  Add try/catch _when you're ready to do something with the exception_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the `AccountNumber` on `lstOfTran`:

```
var lstOfTran = LegalTransactionList.setTransactions();
...
sql.AppendLine("..." + lstOfTran.AccountNumber);
```

but `LegalTransactionList.setTransactions()` returns a *list* of `LegalTransactionRec`s.  The *list* does not have that property, the *items* within the list do.

If you intended to loop over the list of transactions, then it would be something like:

```
StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
var lstOfTran = LegalTransactionList.setTransactions();

foreach (LegalTransactionRec trans in lstOfTran )
{
    sql.AppendLine(" INSERT INTO LEGAL_TRANSCATIONS (BATCH_ID, ACCOUNT, ATTORNEY_ID, ORG_ID, TRANSACTION_DATE, DATE_INSERTED, TRANSACTION_CODE, AMOUNT, DESCRIPTION, DEBTOR_SSN" );
    sql.AppendLine(" VALUES ( (select max(batch_id) from legal_transaction_batch_info),"
                  + trans.AccountNumber + );    
               //   ^-- use loop variable here
}
```

Other things to note:

- Don't swallow exceptions - either handle them or let them bubble up.
- Don't append strings to generate SQL if you can help it - you run the risk of SQL Injection
- If you *do* append strings to get SQL be sure to add a space between strings.  StringBuilder will add a line break which *may* be honored by SQL but better safe than sorry.
- When reading from excel, pull the entire range of values into an array then loop over the array.  `xlRange.Cells[i, j]` calls are COM calls which are VERY expensive.  You'll be surprised how much faster it runs if you pull all of the data into an array first.

Comment: I am new to C# so this kind of went over my head, what are you saying I need to do? I need to look at `LegalTransactionRec` instead of `LegalTransactionList`?

Comment: @user2405778 Your code is confusing - you get a list of transactions, then try to create a `DataTable` by passing an empty sql string (because you haven't added anything to it yet) and loop over _it_.  Did you mean to loop over the list of transactions?

Comment: Yeah I just noticed that, when I added that line I was under the impression it would do something else. I need to remove that, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @user2405778 I added some hints if looping over the transactions was your intent.

Comment: Wow, that actually makes sense. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to access to the property in the list `lstOfTran` of `LegalTransactionRec` type, which need not have a `AccountNumber` property. I think what you're trying to attempt is `lstOfTran[i].AccountNumber`.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:

This line does not even compile:

```
                sql.AppendLine("VALUES ( (select max(batch_id) from legal_transaction_batch_info)," + lstOfTran.AccountNumber + );
```

What is happening after the `+`?

---

Dig into this:

```
AccountNumber = Form1.CleanString(xlRange.Cells[i, 1].Value2.ToString()),
```

It looks like `CleanString()` returns something unexpected. Can you show the implementation?

Comment: I know it doesnt compile, I didnt both adding anything else because the lstOfTran.AccountNumber was giving me an error. I'll add clean string to the OP

Answer (score 2):

`setTransactions()` is returning `List<LegalTransactionRec>`

and you are setting `var lstOfTran` to a List that is returned from

```
LegalTransactionList.setTransactions();
```

You need to specify the item in the list that you are trying to accesss.

try instead:

```
lstOfTran[0].AccountNumber
```

You will probably also have to change

```
sql.AppendLine("VALUES ( (select max(batch_id) from legal_transaction_batch_info)," + lstOfTran.AccountNumber + );
```

To

```
sql.AppendLine("VALUES ( (select max(batch_id) from legal_transaction_batch_info)," + lstOfTran.AccountNumber );
```

note I removed the last `+` after `lstOfTran.AccountNumber`

Comment: That got rid of the error, thank you! Just to make sure I come away with something, I needed to do this to point to the position in which `AccountNumber` is located in the list correct?

Comment: @user2405778 Exactly. You are selecting the first.

Comment: Also the + was there because I will be adding other items from the `List` after `AccountNumber`. I just forgot to remove it when I posted the code. Also thank you for clearing the "why" up!

Comment: @user2405778  please note that `lstOfTran[0]` will ONLY pull the first transaction - you are doing NOTHING with the other transactions that you get.  That may be correct, but it seems unlikely.